# When I ssh to the host in pycharm,after displaying 'Starting the remote IDE backend' for a long time,there shows a Deploy Failed window

Tags: ssh, nohup, stderr

Here.
[image]
They are "nohup:ignoring input" and "stderr is empty".

By the way,in the previous try the number of "nohup:ignoring input" was 3.

And then I remove that connection and take a new connection to the host.The number of "nohup:ignoring input" change to 7 in this picture.

How can I resolve it?